# images failed to load to flutter app from laravel api

Tags: laravel, flutter, api, dart

### **in laravel controller :**

this function to upload data with image :

```
 public function addTrademark(Request $request){
   
       $Trademark = Trademark::where('name',$request->name)->first();
       if($Trademark!=null)
       {
         return response()->json(['message' => 'trademark already Exists']); 
       }
     

      if($request->hasFile('image')){// select request image
        $filename=rand(10000,1000000).$request->image->getClientOriginalName();// add rando to image name
        $request->image->storeAs('images',$filename,'public'); // stor image in server file public/images


        //Storage::disk('public')->put($path .'/'. $filename, base64_decode($image));
        //Storage::disk($path)->put($filename, base64_decode($image));

        $trademark=Trademark::create([
          'name'=>$request->name,
          'image'=>$filename,
         'cretificate'=>$request->cretificate,
         'description'=>$request->description,
         'trader_id'=>$request->trader_id,
         'added_at'=>$request->added_at,
         'Expired_at'=>$request->expired_at,
         'is_active'=>1]);
         return response()->json(['message' => 'success']); 
        }
        else{
          return response()->json(['message' => 'image is empty']); 
        }


api json
-----------
{
  "data": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 37,
        "name": "jjjhhhhg",
        "phone": "778405470",
        "email": "kalid123@gmail.com",
        "address": "حدة",
        "nationality": "يمني",
        "created_at": "2023-03-12T06:35:12.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-03-12T06:35:12.000000Z",
        "image": "404782image_picker1739157224851247651.jpg",
        "cretificate": "https://jjhfss.com",
        "description": "errrrttt",
        "trader_id": 1,
        "added_at": "2023-03-12",
        "Expired_at": "2024-03-12",
        "is_active": 1,
        "trader_name": "خالد جلب"
      },]}}
```

**and this error in flutter :**

---

HttpException: Invalid statusCode: 404, uri = http://10.0.2.2:8000/storage/images//404782image_picker1739157224851247651.jpg

---

**this root of image in flutter :**

---

const String linkimageRoot = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/storage/images/";

---

**and this widget to display image in screen :**

```
ClipOval(
                                                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                                    height: 30,
                                                    width: 30,
                                                    imageUrl:
                                                        "$linkimageRoot/${controller.data[i]['image']}",
                                                    placeholder: (context,
                                                            url) =>
                                                        const Center(
                                                            child:
                                                                CircularProgressIndicator()),
                                                    errorWidget:
                                                        (context, url, error) =>
                                                            Icon(Icons.error),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

There are // after **images** segment in the image url.

http://10.0.2.2:8000/storage/images//404782image_picker1739157224851247651.jpg

Try remove one:

```
 "$linkimageRoot${controller.data[i]['image']}",
```

Or:

```
const String linkimageRoot = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/storage/images";
```

Comment: I deleted it before, same error appeared with one /    ........  HttpException: Invalid statusCode: 404, uri = http://10.0.2.2:8000/storage/images/404782image_picker1739157224851247651.jpg